# Classification of $C_1$ fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, fields

Is there a known complete classification of all $C_1$-fields?

(Definition: A field $k$ is said to be $C_1$ if for every homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables of degree $d$ with $n+1 \ge d$ there exists a solution.)

Any idea or reference for this topic will be much appreciated.

Comment: What would such a classification look like?  There are rather surprising model-theoretic constructions of $C_1$ fields.  There are lists of $C_1$ fields that arise naturally, but I doubt that there *could* be a classification in the sense of listing a few families and saying that there are no others.